# How to normalize an angle between -π and π Java

Tags: java, android, libgdx, normalize, radians

I'm having troubles getting a normalized float to smoothly rotate some sprites.  I'm using interpolation to rotate my sprites.  At a certain point in the rotation the sprite will jump, at the same spot every time.

```
name.angle = (name.getBody().getTransform().getRotation() * alpha + name.prevAngle * (1.0f - alpha));
```

I've looked online and found a couple ways to normalize an angle between -pi and +pi but I can't get them to work in my situation.

The following doesn't work

```
if (name.angle > Math.PI)
    name.angle += 2 * Math.PI;
else if (name.angle < -Math.PI)
    name.angle -= 2 * Math.PI;
```

The following does work

```
name.angle = name.angle < 0 ? MathUtils.PI2 - (-name.angle % MathUtils.PI2) : name.angle % MathUtils.PI2;
```

Comment: You have your pluses and minuses the wrong way round.

Comment: I sure do lol, thanks for helping everyone. I'll try not to make such a silly mistake next time.  But I'm still having problems with the sprite 'jumping'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first code snippet you write

```
if (name.angle > Math.PI)
    name.angle += 2 * Math.PI;
```

This says "if `name.angle` is too big, make it bigger". I have fixed this by changing `+=` to `-=` (and changing `-=` to `+=` in the next bit). I have also replaced `if` with `while`. That way it will still work if the initial angle is more than 2 pi too big/small. The correct code is:

```
double pi = Math.PI;
while (angle > pi)
    angle -= 2 * pi;
while (angle < -pi)
    angle += 2 * pi;
```

Comment: Oh man what a sloppy mistake.  thanks for correcting me.  But I'm still having problems with the sprite 'jumping'.  This is the line I use to interpolate the rotation 
name.angle = (name.getBody().getTransform().getRotation() * alpha + name.prevAngle * (1.0f - alpha));
Besides that, I just set the sprite to the interpolated rotation and and position.  I tried setting the origin of the sprite to the center but that didn't change anything.